# $a^2 - b^2 = bc$, prove $2\alpha = \beta$

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, triangles

> In a triangle with sides $a$, $b$, $c$ and angles $\alpha$, $\beta$,  $a^2 - b^2 = bc$. Prove
>   $2\beta = \alpha$.

I've been trying to solve this for a while, but can't come up with anything useful. I've tried using the sine and cosine rules, to no avail. It seems like it's extremely simple, but I'm missing something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

we have $$a^2=b^2+c^2-2bc\cos(\alpha)$$ with our condition we get
$$1+2\cos(\alpha)=\frac{c}{b}=\frac{\sin(\gamma)}{\sin(\beta)}=\frac{\sin(\alpha+\beta)}{\sin(\beta)}$$ using the addition formuals we obtain
$$1+2\cos(\alpha)=\sin(\alpha)\cot(\beta)+cos(\alpha)$$
now we have
$$2\cos^2\left(\frac{\alpha}{2}\right)=2\sin\left(\frac{\alpha}{2}\right)\cos\left(\frac{\alpha}{2}\right)\cot(\beta)$$ dividing by $$\cos\left(\frac{\alpha}{2}\right)\ne 0$$ we get
$$\tan\left(\frac{\alpha}{2}\right)=\tan(\beta)$$

Comment: yeah it must be $$\alpha=2\beta$$ as i got.

Answer (score 2):

An elementary proof of $\alpha = 2 \beta$

$a^2=b(b+c)$ is given. Let's condider the following figure. Since $|BD|=b+c$, we find that

$$ |BC|^2=|BA|\cdot |BD|$$

Therefore $\triangle DBC \sim \triangle CBA$ (side-angle-side) and $\angle BDC = \angle BCA$. Thus

$$\alpha = 2 \beta $$

[image: a=2b]

**Note:** Furthermore, converse of this proposition proved at [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2247072/finding-side-length-proof-in-double-angle-triangle/2247146#2247146)

Comment: I'm a bit confused - why does $|BC|^2 = |BA| \cdot |BD|$ imply the triangles are congruent by side-angle-side? I see they share side $a, \angle ABC$, but can't see how to use the fact $|BC|^2 = |BA| \cdot |BD|$ from here

Comment: $|BC|^2=|BA|\cdot |BD| \implies \dfrac{|BC|}{|BD|} = \dfrac{|BA|}{|BC|} $. Also, $\angle DBC = \angle CBA$. By side-angle-side similarity, we conclude that $\triangle DBC \sim \triangle CBA$.