# Finding side-length proof in double-angle triangle.

Tags: trigonometry, triangles, angle

In triangle $ABC$, $|AC| = b$ and $|AB| = c$. Angle $A$ is twice angle $B$. Prove that $$|BC| = \sqrt{b\cdot \left(b+c\right)}$$

I understand how to apply laws such as the cosine and sine law to this triangle, but I have no idea how to end up at the desired expression.

Here's a diagram of the triangle:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An elementary solution:

Let's draw $[AD]$ angle biector, $|DB|=x$ and $|DC|=a-x$. Therefore, $\triangle ABC \sim \triangle DAC$ and by properties of ratio

$$ \dfrac ba = \dfrac {a-x}b = \dfrac xc =\dfrac a{b+c}$$

Then $$a^2=b(b+c).$$

[image: figure]

Comment: Thank you for this solution! It was explained very clearly, especially with the use of similar triangles.

Answer (score 0):

Applying the cosine rule in two ways ... we have
\begin{eqnarray*}
a^2=b^2+c^2-2bc \cos(B) \\
c^2=a^2+b^2-2ab \cos(2B)
\end{eqnarray*}
Now reacll the double angle formula $\cos(2B)=2 \cos^2(B)-1$ & after a little algebra
\begin{eqnarray*}
(a^2-bc-c^2)(a+b-c)(a-b+c)(b+c)b=0
\end{eqnarray*}
The latter four factors can be rejected as either the triangle inequality or quantities that are clearly positive ... so we have $a^2-bc-c^2=0$ & the required result follows.