# One angle in a triangle is twice the other, find the relationship among the sides

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles

[image: A random triangle that has sides a,b,c that opposite to the point A,B,C respectively]

$\angle A$ is twice as $\angle B$. I need to find formula that describes relationship among $a,b,c$. It should be a function of only $a,b,c$.

I tried using cosine law and sine law but no result.

Comment: Can you show how you used the sine and cosine laws? Also, do you mean $\angle B$ instead of $\angle b$?

Comment: @ViktorGlombik i could get rid of sin or cos in the equations, i didnt go very far

Comment: I used your diagram to pose its  converse question. Hope it is Ok.

Comment: @Narasimham of course

Comment: Thanks. Deleted the question due to down-votes

Comment: See also: [Finding side-length proof in double-angle triangle.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2247072) and [$a^2 - b^2 = bc$, prove $2\alpha = \beta$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2246705).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\frac{a}{b}=\frac{\sin A }{\sin B}={2\cos B } \tag1$$

which is independent $c $

Apply Cosine Rule and make $c$ to be  $B$ dependent:

$$ c^2= a^2+b^2- 2 a b \cos (\pi- 3B)=a^2+b^2+ 2 a b \cos  (3B)\tag2$$

Now you know $$ \cos 3B = 4 \cos^3 B -3 \cos B  \tag3$$ so eliminate the trig. functions to take it to the next.

EDIT1:

Simplify

$$ \frac{c^2-a^2-b^2}{a}= \frac{a^3}{b^2} -3a \tag4$$

resulting in two simple relations:

$$ a^2-b^2 - bc = 0 ,\quad a^2-b^2+ bc=0 \tag5 $$

This gives

$$ \pm c = \frac{a^2}{b}-b \tag6 $$

A check with right triangle $ (A,B,C)=( 60^{\circ} ,30^{\circ} ,90 ^{\circ}) $ decides that the second relation is to be discarded. $ [2= (\sqrt3)^2-1 ]$

$$  c = \frac{a^2}{b}-b \tag7 $$

which is the required relation. The relation is also checked with geometric construction with angles $ (A,B,C)=( 40^{\circ} ,80^{\circ} ,60 ^{\circ}). $

Comment: The problem is interesting. So I tried to find general Locus of point$C$ for triangle based on $AB=2$ with such double angles in a triangle  [Hyperbola][1]
$$ y^2= (3x+1)(x-1). $$

  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bgOfV.png

Answer (score 3):

$$\cos\alpha=\cos2\beta$$ or $$\sin\alpha=\sin2\beta,$$ which gives 
$$\frac{b^2+c^2-a^2}{2bc}=2\left(\frac{a^2+c^2-b^2}{2ac}\right)^2-1$$ or
$$\frac{a}{b}=\frac{\sin\alpha}{\sin\beta}=\frac{\sin2\beta}{\sin\beta}=2\cos\beta=\frac{a^2+c^2-b^2}{ac}.$$

Comment: Where does the third equation come from

Comment: @Milan I added something. See now.